# Does R have a distinction between character vectors and strings?

Tags: r, string, character

As far as I know, what most languages call a string, R calls a character vector. For example, `"Alice"` is not a string, it's a character vector of length 1. Similarly, `c("Alice", "Bob")` is a character vector of length 2. I cannot recall my IDE or any of my work with R's type system telling me that R has any internal concept of "strings".

Despite this, R's documentation frequently uses the word "string":

- `?paste` and `?nchar` frequently talk of "character strings".
- Many "See Also" sections mention strings without any qualifier, e.g. `?paste`, `?chartr`, and `?agrep`.
- `?strsplit` mentions "substrings".
- `?agrep`, `?toString`, and `?adist` talk about strings both in their titles and "Description" sections.
- `strsplit`, `strwidth`, and `toString` have string or a shorthand for it in their names.

So does R actually have a concept of strings, or does it always mean **exactly** the same thing as "character vector"?

Comment: As far as I know, if they say string they mean exactly a character vector of length 1.

Comment: Most languages also differentiate between a "scalar" and a "vector length 1"; R does not. From a user perspective, there really are no scalars.

Comment: Relevant section from [R Language Definition](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Vector-objects): "R has six basic (‘atomic’) vector types: [...] string (or character)"; "String vectors have mode and storage mode "`character`". A single element of a character vector is often referred to as a _character string_."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting my comment to an answer.

A description of `character` and string can be found in the [R Language Definition](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Vector-objects):

> R has six basic (‘atomic’) vector types: logical, integer, real, complex, **string (or character)** and raw. The modes and storage modes for the different vector types are listed in the following table.

| typeof | mode | storage.mode |
| --- | --- | --- |
| logical | logical | logical |
| integer | numeric | integer |
| double | numeric | double |
| complex | complex | complex |
| **character** | **character** | **character** |
| raw | raw | raw |

[...]

> String vectors have mode and storage mode `"character"`. A single element of a character vector is often referred to as a *character string*.